# Что означает паттерн матчинг с is, пустыми фигурными скобками и идентификатором после них?

Tags: c#, сопоставление-с-образцом

```
document.GetLanguageService<IRemoveUnnecessaryImportsService>() is { } removeUsingsService
```

Тот случай, когда уже перестаёшь понимать родной язык из-за частых изменений. Что тут происходит?

Comment: На англоязычном то СО находится https://stackoverflow.com/a/62140081/8324991

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`is { }` это Property Matching (сопоставление свойств) без указания свойства, является эквивалентом `is not null`.

Например, у меня есть список `List<T>`, и я хочу чтобы выполнилось условие, если он не `null` и сожержит больше 0 элементов.

Раньше я бы написал так.

```
if (list != null && list.Count > 0) { }
```

Ну или так

```
if (list?.Count > 0) { }
```

А теперь это можно сделать так

```
if (list is { Count: > 0 }) { }
```

А если меня не интересует количество элементов в списке, то получится вот так

```
if (list is { }) { }
```

[Документация](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/patterns#property-pattern)

Ну и как в любом сопоставлении с `is` можно результат матчинга привести к целевому типу шаблона написав имя переменной после шаблона.

Общий вид синтаксиса будет выглядеть так

```
obj is <type>
{
    <property_name>: <condition> <constant>,
    <property_name>: <condition> <constant>
}
<assignment_variable>
```